# Close a case X days from its opening - Salesforce

Tags: visual-workflow, case, date, status

What I am trying to do is that when a new case is created, if it does not advance from the new status, it will be closed in 14 days from the date of creation.

[[image]
[[image]
[[image]
[[image]
[image]

I have this trigger-flow but it doesn't do anything (active of course). I understand that when that is fulfilled, I need to change the status to closed.

I have it set to 1 minute from when the test case is created, but it would be 14 days from when it was created.

So, any idea guys?. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please add that image in this question instead of a link.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE! You seem to be going in the right direction, now you should include an Update Element in order to update the Case status. I would advise you to take a look at the [Flow Builder Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-builder) on Trailhead.

Comment: @user1067017 I have this : https://imgur.com/a/rWQOFR2. 
But I don't understand what values ​​to put there

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar done

Comment: Can you share the image what is inside the action to run after 14 days. You may have to check the status of the case and if it is still New then you may need to add an update element to change the status to closed.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I uploaded the photo, it's the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the image the update is not connected to scheduled path. Can you connect it to the scheduled path instead of the immediately . The flow should something as below. This is just the basic flow add if you need any customisation over it

start element:

[image]

Scheduled for 14 days after creation

Decision:

[image]

Update element:

[image]

Total Flow:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did as you have in the photos but it is not closing. I create the case and in a minute it should close. I show you photo of the days (to test I put 1 minute)  https://imgur.com/a/YlVoEf2

Comment: Did you activate the flow and are there any mandatory fields that is not allowing to close the Case. I tried the same flow as above and it closed after 1 Minute.

Comment: I have a validation that from New you can only go to Assigned. That can affect?

Comment: yes if that is the case it is not allowing to change from new to closed. You may need to modify the validation and try.

Comment: If it works, deactivate the VR and everything is great! Thank you very much!!